# Android App Does Not Install Correctly When Running From Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I am building an Android application in Eclipse and I am testing the app on my cell phone (Samsung Galaxy S5).  When I *Run As -> Android Application* in the package explorer with my phone connected the *Console* says that it installed successfully, however, it does not pull up the application on my phone like normal.  It does create an icon in *all apps* but when I click it a toast pops up saying '*Application not installed.*'  There seems to be no problem with Eclipse though because I can run this same process with another Android project and it will work just fine.  I didn't do anything different with my current project.  I did this process successfully with this project and it pulled up like it should before it started not installing correctly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio? It's much better than Eclipse

Comment: You can try following:
1. Check the size of application from Settings->Apps to ensure the app is installed correctly.
2. Uninstall the existing application and install again.
3. Create .apk file and install that file on device just to confirm whether its Connection problem or installation issue.

Comment: I probably should transition to Android Studio but the book that I'm going through right now used eclipse so I figured I'd just stick with that for now.  So how would I go about that 3rd option?

Comment: To export an unsigned APK from Eclipse, right-click the project in the Package Explorer and select Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package. Then specify the file location for the unsigned APK. (Alternatively, open your AndroidManifest.xml file in Eclipse, select the Manifest tab, and click Export an unsigned APK.)

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to android studio. Google stopped supporting eclipse in android development. You may not have added launcher activity in the manifest, check it. Or it should be installation error using usb. Try to copy paste apk from your project bin folder to device and install. If doesn't work show your main class file and manifest file.